# Twitter bootstrap Make first panel of accordion open by default

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am using twitter bootstrap to make accordions on the page. I want to make the first panel open on each page. This is the code that I wrote:

```
    var accordion_list = $(".prime-content .accordion-body");
    accordion_list.each(function(index, element){
      accordion_list.addClass(index == 0 ? "in" : "");
    });
```

This however, is adding "in" class to all the elements. What needs to be fixed?

Comment: use something like eq(), find(), first-child it will solve your problem i think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are adding the class to the whole `accordion_list` collection of elements but you need to add it to the currently iterated element instead.

```
$(".prime-content .accordion-body").each(function(index, element){
  $(element).addClass(index == 0 ? "in" : "");
});
```

If you don't do anything else in the loop you can also make it shorter:

```
accordion_list.first().addClass("in");
```

Comment: first solution is wrong because it's a collection of HTMLElements! second one worked though. Thanks. :)

Comment: Oh you are right, need to create a jquery object from that html element. I corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show the first panel in the accordion:

```
$("#accordion").find('.panel-collapse:first').addClass("in");
```